# How do you save images in an R shiny function

Tags: r, shiny

Generally  the format looks like this

```
output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler
filename = function() {
  paste0(basename(file_path_sans_ext(input$filename)), "_plot", ".jpeg", sep='')
},
PLOTFUNCTION()<- function(){
   plot()

},
content = function(file) {
  if (input$clickButton != 0) {
    jpeg(file)
    PLOTFUNCTION()
    dev.off()
  } 
  else {
    return()
  }
})
```

so then I get this message

**ERROR: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'**
existing posts did not help me as I continue to get this error and the function works outside of the download part, do I need add a a save widget or something?
[R shiny error: Cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430171/r-shiny-error-cannot-coerce-type-closure-to-vector-of-type-double)
 [R error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655967/r-error-cannot-coerce-type-closure-to-vector-of-type-double)

Comment: This error usually comes about because you have forgotten to define something, and the name collides with the name of a function somewhere. Which R usually calls a "closure", because function definitions include the closure of their surrounding environment. So you have an undefined double somewhere. Not sure where, but `plot()` looks kind of strange.

Comment: But as this is not even close to a complete example, I don't see how we can help.

Comment: As @MikeWise said, your code is missing too much details. Normally this error means you are using a function directly as a value, instead of calling the function (i.e. you use `function` instead of `function()`).

Comment: This helped a ton thanks guys!