# SparkR - Error in as.double(x) : cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'

Tags: r, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I want to get some descriptive statistics on my data frame:

```
# Initialize SparkR Contexts
    library(SparkR)                                 # Load library
    sc <- sparkR.init(master="local[4]")            # Initialize Spark Context
    sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)                # Initialize SQL Context

# Load data
df <- loadDF(sqlContext, "/outputs/merged.parquet") # Load data into Data Frame

# Filter 
df_t1 <- select(filter(df, df$t == 1 & df$totalUsers > 0 & isNotNull(df$domain)), "*")

avg_df <- collect(agg(groupBy(df_t1, "domain"), AVG=avg(df_t1$totalUsers), STD=sd(df_t1$totalUsers, na.rm = FALSE)))
head(avg_df)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in as.double(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

which is produced by `sd()`. I tried using `var()` and get `Error: is.atomic(x) is not TRUE`. I get no error when using just `avg()`.

My question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833028/error-in-as-doubley-cannot-coerce-type-s4-to-vector-of-type-double) because I am not using these packages, and reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655967/r-error-cannot-coerce-type-closure-to-vector-of-type-double) I understand that for some reason my `df_t1$tutoalUsers` is a type `S4` instead of vector of double, so I tried casting it with no effect:

```
avg_df <- collect(agg(groupBy(df_t1, "domain"),AVG=avg(df_t1$totalUsers), STD=sd(cast(df_t1$totalUsers, "double"),na.rm = FALSE)))
```

Thoughts?

Edit: The schema is

```
> printSchema(df_t1)
root
 |-- created: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- firstItem: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- domain: string (nullable = true)
 |-- t: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- groupId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- email: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- chat: integer (nullable = true)
```

and my version of Spark is 1.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Spark 1.5 which doesn't provide more advanced statistical summaries and you cannot use standard R functions when operating on Spark `DataFrame`. `avg()` works because it is actually a Spark SQL function available in Spark 1.5.

Additional statistical summaries have been introduced in Spark 1.6 including  methods to compute standard deviation (`sd`, `stddev`       `stddev_samp` and `stddev_pop`) and variance (`var`, `variance`, `var_samp`, `var_pop`). You can of course still compute standard deviation using well known formula as shown in [Calculate the standard deviation of grouped data in a Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31789939/1560062)

Comment: Installing Spark 1.6.2 resolved this problem. Follow up question on Spark 1.6.2, I heard there are issues about splitting too much making it run much slower: any thoughts on that?

Comment: There have been many bugfixes since 1.5 so 1.6+ is nobrainer for me. If properly configured I haven't seen significant performance regressions (although certain operations may be scheduled in a different way so you have to correct for that).