# Error in R: Error in as.numeric(xij)

Tags: r

I am learning using GA and loop with if else function in R, and tried to solve my first problem.

But when I run this code, I get an error like this *`Error in as.numeric(xij) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'`*.Can anyone give me an idea about where I did wrong? I don't know what should I do. I also edit my coding for a few times but still did not get the correct coding. thank you guys so much!

```
attach <- data1
schedule <- as.matrix(data1)
schedule

Jobj Processing_time_Jobj Due_date_Jobj Weighted_Jobj
[1,]    1                   25            61             3
[2,]    2                    7           102             7
[3,]    3                   42            86             1
[4,]    4                   36            44             3
[5,]    5                   18           150             1
[6,]    6                   29           134             4

fitness <- function(j){
for(j in Job){
xij <- function (i,j) if(i==j) 1 else 0
y <- as.numeric(xij)
Cj <- sum((Processing_time_Jobj[j]*xij)+c[j-1])
Lj <- sum((Weighted_Jobj[j]*xij)+(cj[j]-Due_date_Jobj[j]))
}}
GA <- ga(type = "permutation", fitness = fitness, lower = 1, upper = 500)
```

> Error in as.numeric(xij) :  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of
>   type 'double'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655967/r-error-cannot-coerce-type-closure-to-vector-of-type-double)

Answer (score 0):

`xij` has been defined as function of two arguments

```
xij <- function (i,j) if(i==j) 1 else 0
```

The next statement

```
y <- as.numeric(xij)
```

is causing the error message.

`xij` needs to be called with some arguments, e.g.,

```
as.numeric(xij(2,3))
```

> ```
> [1] 0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you print out `xij`, you see it's a function and not a numeric.

You should replace this line with

```
xij <- ifelse(i==j, 1, 0)
```

and get get rid of the `y` variable